# How to implement the MonadState class without using record syntax?

Tags: haskell, monads, ghc, monad-transformers, state-monad

I find it difficult for me to understand the **MonadState** .

The reason maybe most of the examples mixing up with record syntax in their data structure.

So, I tried to implement the **MonadState** without using record syntax.

The following code I wrote did pass the compiler, but it seems totally nonsense to me.

What is wrong with these code?

Is there a simple example of implementing **MonadState** without using record syntax?

```
data Foo a b = Foo (Maybe ([a],b)) deriving (Show)

unwrapFoo :: Foo a b -> Maybe ([a],b)
unwrapFoo (Foo x) = x

instance Monad (Foo [a]) where
  return x = Foo $ Just ([], x) 
  m >>= f  = case unwrapFoo m of
               Just (_, r) -> f r
               Nothing     -> Foo Nothing 

instance MonadState Int (Foo [a]) where
  get   = Foo $ Just ([], 1)     
  put _ = Foo $ Just ([],())


*Main> get :: Foo [a] Int
Foo (Just ([],1))
*Main> put 3 :: Foo [a] ()
Foo (Just ([],()))
*Main>
```

Comment: What's wrong is that you don't really have a state-ful data type here, so you can't implement a meaningful `MonadState` instance. There's little point learning how to implement "just some instance" for a specific class, what you rather want to do is you design a data type to fit the requirements of various classes. Or, you design a data type for some problem, and suddenly notice "hey, this thing behaves much like the `State` monad. Perhaps it should be an instance of `MonadState`"? – Normally, there's no need to do it for the `Monad*` classes anyway, just use a suitable transformer stack.

Comment: Start with `newtype Foo s a = Foo (s -> (s, a))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So let's start with the basic idea of the State Monad.

```
newtype MyState s a = MyState (s {- current state -}
                           -> (s {- New state -}, a {- New value -}))

unwrap (MyState f) = f
```

So now we need to implement `>>=` and `return`.

`return` is pretty easy:

```
return a = MyState $ \s -> -- Get the new state
                     (s, a) -- and pack it into our value
```

In other words, this just passes the current state through with a new value.

And now `>>=`

```
(MyState f) >>= g = MyState $ \state -> 
    let (newState, val) = f state
        MyState newF    = g val
    in newF state
```

So we get a new state, feed it into our existing state monad, then pass the resulting value/state pair into `g` and return the result of that.

The total number of differences between this and the record syntax is just that I had to manually define `unwrap`.

To complete our monad

```
runState = unwrap

get = MyState \s -> (s, s)
put a = MyState \s -> (a, ())
```

Comment: I've seen almost all examples implementing MonadState with a data type which is actually a wrapper of a function of type `(s -> (s, a))`. Is it possible to get rid of the inner function?

Comment: Not really, that's pretty much what the state monad is.

Comment: @jozefg I think it should've been: `in newF newState` instead of `in newF state` in your definition of bind